# Accessing Sharepoint from outside the WebUI

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharepoint

Is it possible to access the database backend of a sharepoint server? My company uses Sharepoint to store data and pictures of various assets. Ideally I would be able to access the data and display it in my application to allow users both methods of access.

Before I go talk to the IT department I would like to find out if this is even possible?

Edit: From rails on linux? (Yes, I know I'm crazy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Adam. Querying the Sharepoint Database is a big no-no, as Microsoft does not guarantee that the Schema is in any way stable. Only access the database if there is really no other way.

As for Sharepoint, usually the Lists.asmx Web Service is what you want to look at first.

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WSSInNet01302007093018AM/WSSInNet.aspx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-sharepoint-portal-server-using-web-services-in-net/)

[http://geekswithblogs.net/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221152136/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

yikes! :)

look at the web service and .net API before going direct to the database.  i've used both and they provide plenty of flexibility (including building your own web services on top of the API if necessary).  API for on server clients, web services for off server clients.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small comment. Never ever go to the database direct. If there is no way to do it via published and supported API's, then there is no way to do it. End of story. This applies even to when you are "just reading data", as this can still cause significant issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just to support the above if you ever take a look at the SQL tables that sit behind SharePoint you'll realise why its not recommnded or supported to access the database direct.  MADNESS!